# Drawing axis only in $\Bbb R_{++}$, but tags in $\Bbb R$

Tags: plotting, legending

I'm sketching a diagram in $\Bbb R_{++}$ and I want to indicate the coordinates of some points. I want to place labels below the $x$ axis and to the left of the $y$ axis. But if I set `PlotRange->{{0,Maxplot},{0,Maxplot}}`, labels are not shown. If I enlarge the `PlotRange`, then axis extend into $x<0$ and $y<0$.

My code

```
A = {50, 25};
B = {25, 50};
F = (3*B + A)/4;
Maxplot = 70;
Show[ListPlot[{F}, PlotStyle -> Black, PlotRange -> {{-10, Maxplot}, {-5, Maxplot}}, AspectRatio -> 1, AxesLabel -> {L, K}, Ticks -> None], 
Graphics[{Text["L + ΔL", {F[[1]], -2}],Text["K -s ΔL", {-5, F[[2]]}], Line[{{B[[1]], Maxplot}, B, A, {Maxplot, A[[2]]}}], Dotted, Line[{{F[[1]], 0}, F}],Line[{{0, F[[2]]}, F}]}]]
```

I'm sure that my code can be improved in many other ways, feel free to comment!

Comment: Could you explain further what you mean by "I'd rather have tags for referencing. I do not know how to do that without having the axis extend into 'negative territory.'"? It is not really clear to me.

Comment: Sorry, @C.E. What I meant is that I want to place labels below the x axis and to the left of the y axis. But if I set `PlotRange->{{0,Maxplot},{0,Maxplot}}` labels are not shown. If I enlarge the `PlotRange` then axis extend into $x<0$ and $y<0.$

Comment: Since you do not really want to "plot" but rather "draw", it might be better to build the image you want using `Graphics` for everything. (I had a look at how axes are handled in Mathematica and it seems that even if you do limit the `PlotRange` to a certain range, the axes still extend to infinity and I do not see a clean way to solve this issue.)

Comment: @Natas. Would `AxesOrigin` do the trick? In my example there's just one point, but in fact I have quite a few...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using the option `Ticks` seems to do the trick. Also, instead of combining graphics with `Show` it is easier (and perhaps more robust) to use `Epilog`.

```
ListPlot[{F},
 PlotStyle -> Black,
 AspectRatio -> 1,
 AxesLabel -> {"L", "K"},
 PlotRange -> {{0, Maxplot}, {0, Maxplot}},
 Ticks -> {{{F[[1]], "L+\[CapitalDelta]L"}}, {{F[[2]], 
     "K-s \[CapitalDelta]L"}}},
 Epilog -> {Line[{{B[[1]], Maxplot}, B, A, {Maxplot, A[[2]]}}], 
   Dotted, Line[{{F[[1]], 0}, F}], Line[{{0, F[[2]]}, F}]}
 ]
```

[image: Using Ticks to have the axes not extend into the negative domain.]